# Remove spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I've uploaded and deployed some spfx webparts through my App Catalog site.

Now these webparts are not useful anymore so I've deleted them from the App Catalog.

Then I've checked my sites and modified modern pages and I've seen that these webparts are still listed even if they were deleted and even if they are not listed in site contents page.

I've also waited and re-check after a week, but webparts are still listed when I open a page in edit mode.

Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: @Pepozzon, webparts won't get deleted automatically. There are two options: either delete them manually from every page or write a script that does it.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov thank you! I'm sorry, I did not explain myself well. I've already removed weparts from site pages, but when I click on "+" button I found them listed as webparts I can add to my page. Obviously when I click on a webpart I receive a rendering error on the page.

Comment: Check if those web parts are listed under "Site contents". If they are, try removing them from there and they should not be visible in web part picker again.

Comment: @DamjanTomic Hi Damjan! I've already checked and they're not listed in Site Contents.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the issue and it is very annoying..

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have delete the SPFx web part from the recycle bin, both from the first stage and second stage recycle bin.

I suggest you follow the article below to uninstall(Remove) SPFx web part in SharePoint Online.

[To uninstall (Remove) SPFx web part in SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uninstall-remove-the-apps-or-client-side-webpart-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Hi! I've followed that article before. I've checked recycle bins after your comment and I've found .sppkg files there so I've deleted these files. Now I still see webpart listed when I try to edit a page, but I'll check again later.

Comment: Did you check the second stage recycle bin?

Comment: Yes, I deleted sppkg files from the second stage recycle bin as well. However I keep seeing wepart listed when I modify a modern page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the features for those webparts is still shown in the site/sitecollection features option? I've had some occasions where deleting the packages didn't delete the features for reasons unknown. Other times, the deletion took a lot of time (24h+)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have references to these webparts in site features and in sitecollection features.

Comment: Me too. Any PowerShell to get rid of this?